# what is a good way of finding duplicates in datomic?

Tags: datomic

I have a bunch of records containing business names and I wish to do a query to find all the duplicates. How can this be done?

```
{:business/name "<>"}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're trying to enforce uniqueness on the attribute value you should look at the `:db/unique` [schema attribute](http://docs.datomic.com/schema.html) instead.

To find the duplicated values **and** how often they repeat, use:

```
(->> (d/datoms db :aevt :business/name)
   (map :v)
   (frequencies)
   (filter #(> (second %) 1)))
```

which uses the [`datomic.api/datoms`](http://docs.datomic.com/clojure/#datomic.api/datoms) API to access the raw AEVT index to stream `:business/name` attribute values, calculate their frequency and filter them based on some criteria i.e. more than one occurrence. You can also achieve the same result using datalog and [aggregation functions](http://docs.datomic.com/query.html):

```
(->> (d/q '[:find (frequencies ?v)
      :with ?e
      :in $ ?a
      :where [?e ?a ?v]]
    db :business/name)
 (ffirst)
 (filter #(> (second %) 1)))
```

To find the entities with duplicated attribute values, use:

```
(->> (d/datoms db :aevt :business/name)
   (group-by :v)
   (filter #(> (count (second %)) 1))
   (mapcat second)
   (map :e))
```

which also leverages the `d/datoms` API to accomplish it. For a full code sample, including datalog implementations, see https://gist.github.com/a2ndrade/5641681

Comment: Thanks! Basically, I'm trying to establish uniqueness after the data has been loaded in... Maybe that's not such a good idea..

Comment: It's a bad idea **unless** your database is so large than `:business/name` values can't fit in the transactor's memory. In that case, uniqueness constraints will dominate transaction times as the transactor may need to query/decompress a big number of segments from storage, which also may push out other _hot_ data from cache.

Comment: @a2ndrade what about duplicates based on multiple datoms? :busines/name and :business/zipcode?